# Seamless scrolling of QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsplitter, qt5.6

I have a widget with a splitter, see below

[image: QSplitter]

My problem is that I can adjust the splitting only in some range. I can adjust the upper part `fr_SelectModel` (red) to 100%. Then I can seamlessly adjust the lower part `frp_Editors` between 0-30%, thereafter it snaps to 100%.

[image: upper part 100%] [image: lower part 20%] [image: lower part snaps to 100%]

What I want is that I can adjust both parts ( `fr_SelectModel` / `frp_Editors` ) between 0-100%. I understand that I can enable/disable the snapping

```
        ui->sp_MappingComponent->setCollapsible(0, true);
        ui->sp_MappingComponent->setCollapsible(1, true);
```

but it does not help. So what does cause the restriction that I cannot further reduce the upper part?

Comment: Have you tried setting collapsible to `false`?

Comment: yes, then it is even further restricted as I can not reduce the upper / lower part to 0%. I can move the splitter then between 10-30%

Comment: Have you set minimum sizes for any of the widgets?

Comment: Just had the same idea and went thru all widgets - nope, no minimum size